# how much do I really need to know to become Jr Developer?

Tags: asp.net, junior-programmer

I believe I have a very good understanding of programming logic fundamentals (passing around variables, nested conditional statements, etc). I am currently going through a book on ASP.NET and am pretty much lost on all the Page Rendering Model, Custom Rendered Controls, Composite Controls, etc. I understand how to use the standard controls no problem. Do I really need to understand all those other things to become a junior developer? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Don't be afraid to try third party libraries like NHibernate, Log4Net, etc. Every object is a first class citizen in .net.

Comment: Build a solid foundation - learn data structures and algorithms and then move up the stack.  It takes discipline but it's easier to learn higher level concepts once you understand the foundations.  It's much harder to learn the foundations if you've onl done higher level stuff and glazed over how things work.

Comment: A little bit less than a senior developer.  :-)

Answer (score 9):

A Junior Developer needs to have the basics down.  In your field, that would include a pretty firm grasp on OOP, the layout of ASP.NET applications, master pages, code behind (whether it be C# or VB.NET), etc.  Basically the stuff you can pick up with personal projects.  Everything else is just gravy.

The specifics, like composite controls and page rendering will be picked up and mastered while actually utilizing the certain technology.  **Nobody is going to expect you to walk in the front door and be a master with ASP.NET**.  You are young and your experience dictates that.  Even the best developers aren't born knowing this stuff.  They know it because they've used it....*for many, many years*.

**BUT MOST IMPORTANTLY**:
Just be willing to learn and listen to the mid-level and senior developers.

Answer (score 4):

I think as a Jr Developer (I am one) you should be where you are at; solid knowledge of fundamentals, eagerness to learn and an open mind. You will consolidate your skills as you are introduced to new problems to solve. I think technology-specific skills are developed and learned on the job, at least that's what I've found. Good luck!

Comment: Not much actually. The point of being junior is that you have theoretical knowledge with little practical experience. Pharma_joe above said it well.

Answer (score 3):

The truth is: it depends on company and on the meaning of junior position. Sometimes junior is equal to graduate and sometimes junior is above graduate.

Some companies expects that you know what ASP.NET is. Some companies expects that you know what .NET and C# is and some companies expects that you know what HTTP and web development is.

If junior = graduate you can find companies where simple diploma from information technology  related is enough (= theoretical knowledge) and company will teach you what they need. It doesn't mean you don't have to learn yourselves - self learning is the most important part of your career development.

The question is if ASP.NET WebForms are what you should learn? Definitely check ASP.NET MVC as well. Also being ASP.NET developer is not only about .NET - you should learn JavaScript and some JavaScript framework (like jQuery). Knowledge of HTML (especially HTML 5) and CSS can be also very useful.

Answer (score 0):

i see your post and i amazed me that you are asking for Jr developer.
You just prepare your old projects what you have done in your college and company. after completing you'll see that you prepare some more new things and it will really help you to clear the Jr developer interview.